# How to open specific PHP function in server?

Tags: php, curl

I am facing to use some php function in my site. 
Such as : `CURL Function` . 
It is showing safe mode error ( like something this ) in erro_log . 
How can i open specific php function for my site.Is it matter of `.htaccess` Or i need to contact with hosting company for this ?

Here is my sample error log : 
`[03-Dec-2012 01:27:18] PHP Warning:  set_time_limit() [<a href='function.set-time-limit'>function.set-time-limit</a>]: Cannot set time limit in safe mode in ....`

Comment: hi, slash show your actual error from log file here..

Comment: If this is a shared host, you need to contact your host. If this is a VPS or dedicated server, you can edit your `php.ini` file to disable the safe mode restrictions.

Comment: @DanGrossman This is share host. So, i need to contact with provider.

Comment: hey put <?php  phpinfo(); ?> and check, I assume that CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated,

Comment: @wiramrathod , 
hello, i have added a log error in my post. please check it. Thanks.

Comment: @slash-bang put ini_get('safe_mode'); in your php code,
and check if PHP is compiled with --enable-safe-mode then defaults to On, otherwise Off.